# whoosh_search() returns empty

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, whoosh

Tutorial at http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WhooshAlchemy/ works for me.

Here's my setup

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    __searchable__ = ['body']

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String)
```

Results:

If I do not put `whoosh_index()` before `whoosh_search()`, I get the error:
`AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'whoosh_search'`

`db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.body=='hi')` returns the correct output.
`Post.query.whooshee_search('hi')` returns empty

I did leave some code out, like additional columns and backrefs, but I don't think that changes anything

There are a few things to note:

- Tutorial worked fine without `whoosh_index()`, but my code threw error
  when I did not include it.
- `db.session.query(Post).filter()` code worked fine, indicating my model is at least somewhat correct, and there is something wrong with whoosh/my whoosh setup

Please help, thanks

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. Any progress with this?

Comment: @onepiece couldn't it just simply be because you perform `whoosh_search` on posts which have not been indexed (created beforehand) ?

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the same issue as `Post.query.whoosh_search('post').all()` returned empty list all the time.

I found that it can be solved with using the specific versions specified here
`https://github.com/gyllstromk/Flask-WhooshAlchemy/blob/master/requirements.txt`

I was using following versions:

Flask==0.10.1

```
Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.1

Whoosh-2.7.2

blinker-1.4
```

I ***replaced*** them with:

```
**Flask==0.10.1**

**Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0**

**Whoosh==2.6.0**

**blinker==1.3**
```

---

I will update here once I find exactly which upgrade causes this problem and why.